# get mysql data where column has 2 values

Tags: mysql

I have the following mysql query:

```
SELECT * FROM `notifications` 
WHERE `receiverUserID` = 3 AND `status` = 0 AND `typ` = 1 OR `typ` = 2
```

the result:

[image]

But my query is not correct.
The result should show me only data where typ = 1 OR 2, status = 0 and the receiverUserID = 3

the row where receiverUserID = 2 should not be shown.
Where is my mistake ?

Comment: `WHERE \`receiverUserID\` = 3 AND \`status\` = 0 AND (\`typ\` = 1 OR \`typ\` = 2)`

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Note that the row with `receiverUserID = 3` should also not be shown since it has `status = 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to shorten down the scope of OR operator by using parenthesis. So your query should be

```
SELECT * FROM notifications
WHERE receiverUserID = 3 AND status = 0 AND (typ = 1 OR typ = 2 );
```

**Edit 1 (Helpful comment by @jBuchholz)**

Here is a list of operator precedences in MySQL dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html `AND` has higher precedence than OR and is therefore executed earlier (like multiplication is executed before addition).

Comment: In addition: here is a list of operator precedences in mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html
`AND` has a higher precedence than `OR` and is therefore executed earlier (like multiplication is executed before addition).

Comment: @jBuchholz Thanks a lot for adding a much valuable thing. Appreciate it. If you allow, may I add it in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what your query was actually doing:

```
SELECT * FROM
notifications
WHERE (receiverUserID = 3 AND status = 0 AND typ = 1) OR typ = 2;
```

This is due to that `AND` takes greater *precedence* than `OR`.  This explains why all those `typ = 2` records appear in your result set.
You need to use parentheses to enforce the and/or logic you have in mind:

```
SELECT * FROM
notifications
WHERE receiverUserID = 3 AND status = 0 AND (typ = 1 OR typ = 2);
```

Note that had used `WHERE IN (...)` syntax this would have been a moot point:

```
SELECT * FROM
notifications
WHERE receiverUserID = 3 AND status = 0 AND typ IN (1, 2);
```